# Adding truncated normals: calculating convolutions

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, convolution

Problem:

Suppose that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent standard normal random variables.

What is the probability of:
\begin{equation} 
P\{ X+Y+Z+\Delta>0 \, | \, Z+\Delta>0, \, Y+Z+\Delta>0 \}
\end{equation}

Where $\Delta>0$ is a real number.

---

I have been trying to solve this problem by using convolutions to get a distribution for a random variable (and then calculate the probability that it is less than zero).

My method has been to address the problem as:

Let $X\sim N(0,1)$, $Y\sim TN(0,1;0,\infty)$, and $Z\sim TN(\Delta,1;0,\infty)$ be independent random variables; then the sum of them:
\begin{equation}
W = X + Y + Z
\end{equation}
is distributed according to the pdf:
\begin{equation}
f_W (x) = \, ?
\end{equation}

What is the probability given by:

\begin{equation}
\int^{0}_{-\infty}f_W(x)\, dx = \, ?
\end{equation}

---

Note: $N(0,1)$ denotes a [standard normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution); $TN(\mu,\sigma;a,b)$ is a [truncated normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) where $a$ and $b$ are the the lower and upper bounds of the truncation respectively.

I know that the distribution of $W$ is given from the [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$:

\begin{equation}
f_W = f_X \ast f_Y \ast f_Z
\end{equation}

The convolution operator obeys commutativity and associativity.

---

Here is what I have shown so far:

\begin{equation}
f_X \ast f_Y = \sqrt{2}\, \phi\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \, \Phi\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
f_X \ast f_Z = \left[\sqrt{2} \, \Phi\left( \Delta \right)\right]^{-1}\phi\left( \frac{x-\Delta}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \, \Phi\left( \frac{x+\Delta}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
\end{equation}

And I have also shown (to somewhat abuse notation):
\begin{equation}
f_{X\ast Y}(x) \ast f_{Z}(x) =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\Phi(\Delta)} \phi\left( \frac{x-\Delta}{\sqrt{3}} \right) \int_{-\infty}^{x} \phi\left(\frac{ 3u-2(x-\Delta)}{\sqrt{6}} \right)  \,  \Phi\left( \frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \right)  \,  du
\end{equation}

Which, as far as I can tell, does not really simplify any further.  I've tried integration by parts on the last integral but it does not seem to help very much.  My question is two-fold:

- First, is there a "nice" formula for $f_W(x)$?  I can't get much further than what I've written above.  My intuition is "no" since this is effectively looking for an analytical solution to the volume under a bivariate normal distribution.
- Second, is it possible to calculate the probability that $W$ is less than zero?

---

As an aside, I have asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583568/integrating-a-special-skew-normal-the-cdf-of-a-convolution-of-a-normal-with-a) on a related topic.

The question has been edited to reflect that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent (thanks to @DilipSarwate for pointing this out).

Comment: Your calculations **assume** that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are _independent_ random variables; else the convolution you are using does not apply It might be easier to assume that $X,\hat{Y}, \hat{Z}$ are independent unit-variance normal random variables with means $0, 0, \Delta$ respectively and then calculate $P\{X+\hat{Y}+\hat{Z} > 0 \mid \hat{Y} > 0, \hat{Z} > 0\}$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks for the comment.  They are, in fact, independent.  I'll edit the question so as to reflect this.

Comment: @DilipSarwate -- Regarding calculating $P\{ X+Y+Z | Y>0,Z>0 \}$, this is precisely the problem I am trying to solve.  To give some more background, I am thinking about some variable evolving over time; in each time period a new independent standard normal error term is added on.  The initial starting point of the variable is $\Delta$ and if the variable ever drops below 0 then the process ends.  I want to know the probability that the variable drops below 0 _in_ the 2nd period (conditional on it having survived the 0th and 1st periods).

Comment: So what you want to find is $P\{\Delta+X+Y+Z>0\mid \Delta+X>0, \Delta+X+Y> 0\}$ where $X$,$Y$, and $Z$ is independent standard normal random variables? If so, why not edit your question some more to say so?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, that is a very clear way of formulating the problem!   Thanks for the suggestion -- I've updated the post accordingly.  (I'll also have think about this, maybe my method of convolutions is over-complicating the problem...)

Comment: Why can't be Y negative??? IMHO the reformulation is wrong.